# Removing print text in the print preview joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Did someone knows how to remove the print text preview button in print preview pages in joomla? because i just want to print all the information in the article without the print text in the first line of the paper thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Without a screenshot it's not really clear which button you are talking about.

In any case you can target the style for the printer in 2 ways

One is directly pasting this in your css file

```
@media print {
    #pop-print {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

`@media print` is the media query for the printer [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) you can read the documentation.

The other way is generate a specific css just for the printer, eg printer.css.

In this case in your `<head>` you have to insert

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' href='printer.css' />
```

and after in printer.css you can insert the same code as above but that time you don't need `@media print` .

Note:
If it's just for this time the first solution it's ok, if you have to work a lot on the print layout I suggest to use the second method.

Comment: i cant upload any photos because of my reputation sorry but do you know how to remove the "print"text in the print preview page when you want to print an article in joomla 3.0? @borracciaBlu